# Derivative of a function with respect to a specific change of another function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let's consider two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$. Function $f$ is defined as:

$f(x)=\frac{e^{-g(x)}}{\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-g(y)} \,\text{d}y}$

I would like to determine the sign of the derivative of $f$ regarding to a change of function $g$ as follow:

$\text{d}\,g(x)=0$ for $x\leq X$, and $\text{d}\,g(x)>0$ for $x>X$.

With such change, I would expect:

$\text{d}\,f(x)>0$ for $x\leq X$ (via a change in the denumerator), and $\text{d}\,f(x)<0$ for $x<X$ (via a change in the numerator).

I can solve $\frac{\text{d}\,f(x)}{\text{d}\,g(x)}$. But I don't know how to deal with such specific changes of $\text{d}\,g$. Could you please give me a hand?

PS: I am not a mathematician by training. Sorry if the notations are a bit clumsy.

Comment: $f'(x)=\frac{-g'(x) e^{-g(x)}}{\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-g(y)} \,\text{d}y}$.Now $ e^{-g(x)}$ is always positive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But you did not account for the change of $g$ in the integral, right?

Comment: Integral is a constant so it has a fixed sign for example when $g(x)=x$, the integral is 1.Or if I consider your constraint suppose $g(x)=1\forall x\leq2$ and $g(x)=x \forall x>2$. Then integral is $2e^{-1}+e^{-2}$.

Comment: So sign of  $f '$ depends only upon the value of the integral and sign of $g'(x)$

Comment: But then, $\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-g(y)-\text{d}\,g(y)} \,\text{d}y$ will also change?

Answer (score 1):

Let $c:=\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-g(y)} dy.$ Then $f(x)= \frac{1}{c}e^{-g(x)} .$

Hence

$$f'(x)=\frac{-g'(x)}{c}e^{-g(x)}.$$

Thus

$$ f'(x) >0 \iff \frac{g'(x)}{c} <0$$

and

$$ f'(x) <0 \iff \frac{g'(x)}{c} >0.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what if the shape of the function $g$ is changing in a certain way? How would it affect function $f$, givent that this change in the function $g$ would also change the integrale value?

Comment: In other words, the shape of the function $g$ is changing, and not the variable $x$.